# British way to say £1.99 and €1.01 and €1.01

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, british-english, reading-aloud

Are the following usages correct in BrE?

> £1.01
>
> 1. One pound one.
> 2. One pound and one pence.
> 3. One pound one pence.
> 4. One pound and one.
> 5. One one

> $1.01
>
> 1. One dollar  one.
> 2. One dollar and one cent.
> 3. One dollar one cent.
> 4. One dollar and one.
> 5. One one

> €1.01
>
> 1. One euro one.
> 2. One euro  and one cent.
> 3. One euro one cent.
> 4. One euro and one.
> 5. One one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1), (2) and (3) are the most common. (4) is borderline and (5) is definitely wrong.

If it was a common price like £1.20 then "one pound twenty" or "one twenty" would be by far the most common but with it being the more awkward amount of £1.01 then it makes adding the "pence" more likely.

However in colloqual spoken English it is fairly rare to say "pence". Brits would say "p" (pee), and a likely phrasing of £1.01 is "One pound one p".

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, 'pence' is the plural of 'penny'. One penny, two pence. You will sometimes hear 'one pence' said, but it sounds ignorant to many people. This is opinion-based, but I would say that for all those currencies, 1, 2, and 3 are OK, 4, is rare, and 5 very rare or nonexistent for e.g. £1.01 (Maybe 'one oh one' though). You may hear £4.99 said as 'four ninety-nine'.

Answer (score 4):

I can speak for contemporary British usage. The others not so much.

£1.01 is a fairly uncommon amount to hear in a shop, because prices near the pound are usually £n.99 or £n.95 etc., in which case "n ninety-nine" etc. is de rigueur.

Recently though, a law was introduced whereby plastic bags have to be charged to the customer at 5p each. When this is added to a purchase of 99p, £1.04 would no longer be uncommon and colloquially usage would usually be "one oh four".

Context would make the units apparent. The purchaser would "know" this was a small amount and therefore around the one pound mark, so "one oh four" would be automatically understood as being £1.04.

Exactly the same applies to £1.01, which would be voiced "one oh one", or perhaps "one pound oh one".

You might hear "one pound and one p" (if the vendor wanted to be particularly precise), as "p" is standard for announcing the units of pence.

We hardly ever say "pennies" or "pence". It's practically always "p" pronounced "pee". Despite the opportunity here for ribald jokes, this is practically unnoticed by contemporary Brits.

£101 would be spoken "a hundred and one (pounds)".

Comment: Thank you all so much for answers. An additional question, if you please. "P" is the abbreviation for "pennies," "pence" and "penny" but not for "pound". Right? I have an old book in which there is an explanation about the difference between "pennies" and "pence". It says "pennies" refer to a few coins each  worth one pence. "Pence" refers to one coin which is worth a few pence.  It's a Georgian textbook.

Comment: @AntoniaA Careful. it's *lowercase* "p" and not uppercase "P" which is the abbreviation for "pence". And never for "pounds", which is "£". (Sorry, I thought that was clear from my post.) "Pence" is the word for the financial quantity 2p+. "Pennies" is the plural of "penny" and would be used for a quantity of the *actual coins*. "I have 5 pennies in my pocket" means you have 5 coins all of which are pennies. "I have fivepence in my pocket" means I have a quantity of money amounting to 5p, which may be all pennies or, e.g. may be one 5p coin, or two 2p coins and a 1p coin.

Comment: @AntoniaA By "Georgian textbook" does that mean it dates back to the Georgian era in British history, or is it published in the state of Georgia? If the former, then this means *old* pennies, whose abbreviation was "d". New pence only came into being in the 1970s.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Sounds almost exactly analogous to use of "penny/pennies" and "cent/cents" in the USA.  The penny is the coin denominated one cent.  Except that it seems there is no British equivalent to that sentence, because there's no singular of pence parallel to "cent" being the singular of cents?

Comment: @BenVoigt The singular of "pence" is "penny". The singular of "pennies" is also "penny". But one refers to the monetary quantity and the other refers to the coins. And when you say "one penny", the monetary quantity *and* the coin are (to a certain level of linguistic approximation) the same thing. The fact that in American English the word "penny" actually means "cent" is a confusion which will need to be resolved separately.

Comment: @PrimeMover: In American English the word "penny" does not have the same meaning as "cent".  "Penny" is the coin, "cent" is the monetary quantity.

Comment: @BenVoigt What I said, a "penny" is a "cent".

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't clear. I meant a textbook written by Georgian linguiststs in Georgia, Eastern Europe. Let me rephrase some explanations so that I know for sure I don't misunderstand anything. Lowercase "p" is the abbreviation for both "penny" and "pence". Before the new penny was introduced the abbreviation for 1  penny  not 1  pence was "d". Is that right?

Comment: @AntoniaA That is correct. The words "penny", "pennies" and "pence" are the same for new and old, and during the early days of decimal currency, the word "new" was usually attached to the new currency. In fact, coins minted in the first decade of the decimal era (1971-1981 approximately) had "new penny" and "new pence" on them. After that time, the design said "one penny" or "two pence" or "five pence" or whatever, and that is how they are now.

Comment: Do native speakers use "p" for "pennies" as well? I asked about "penny" and "pence" but forgot about "pennies." If 5p is understood as five pence or five pennies the total amount is 5, then it's not wrong to write "5 pennies"  and the "p" in 5p is understood as either pence or pennies. Right?

Answer (score 1):

**When talking about money, 'p' after a coin or amount sounds the same as the letter 'p' /piː/.**

50 pence coin ✔︎ (formal) or 50p coin ✔︎ (colloquial)

20 pence coin ✔︎ (formal) or 50p coin ✔︎ (colloquial)

I had £1.01 (one pound one p) in my change jar. ✔︎

I had £1.01 (one 0 one) in coins. ✘  *Not said in British English

Answer (score -3):

I would refer to £1.01 as one pound and one pence, or another example £3.27 as three pounds and twenty seven pence.

Learners of English may well meet a wide range of native English speakers, from all sorts of backgrounds and class, and so it may well be that there is no correct answer.

Comment: Haven't said "pence" for almost 5 decades. It's "p" and always has been, wherever I've been, ever since we were 3 months into decimalisation. Oh, and it was 50 years ago. I remember, I was there.

Comment: Surely even in 1971 the 1p coin was called a "new penny".  According to https://www.mirror.co.uk/money/rare-most-valuable-1p-coin-7944008 : "The original design - with 'New Penny' on the back and the Arnold Machin portrait of the Queen on the front - was used unchanged for 10 years".

Comment: The decimalised penny was called a 'new penny', not 'a pence'. 'One pence' is _wrong_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Wrong or not, I contend that it just wouldn't be heard in the first place. "Pee" is ubiquitous. But then if people *are* using "one pence" (which I confess is actually far more likely to hear than "one penny"), then that's what is being used and arguing "wrongness" is less relevant.

Comment: @PrimeMover - swapping singular/plural when talking about currency (one pence, five pound) is not unknown, but decidedly non-standard, and liable to be perceived as ignorant or uneducated.

Comment: "The use of *pence* rather than *penny* as a singular ... is not regarded as correct in standard English" (Lexico).  The OED entry has recently been updated and comments on this usage: "frequently regarded as a solecism".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "liable to be perceived as ignorant or uneducated" -- personally, I'm not so sure it would; if so, then such usage would probably be considered appropriate to the milieu in which it was heard. It would above all sound *British* ignorant and uneducated, and hence standard. I would not be willing to guess how correction of a person's style would be accepted in day-to-day discourse.

Comment: There is nothing 'decimal' about the word 'pence', it has always been a plural of 'penny', hence sixpence, threepence, tuppence, etc.